# MySQL + PHP: HTML Style

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was wondering if somebody could help me with a little code:

I have a database with a TEXT column called style. I want to specify a range of html tags, for example:

```
<h1><b><u><i>
```

Then I want PHP to read it and place the column title inside those tags and automatically close the html tags from my style column. I tried to find out but can't find any solution.

I tried this, but don't know if there's a better way:

```
echo "<li id=''><a href='$navigator[link]'><span>$navigator[style]$navigator[title]" . str_ireplace($navigator['title'], '<', '</') . "</span></a></li>";
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Look at my edited post. I'm wondering if there's a better way than what I tried.

Comment: So you want to fill attributes of tags from a database with php?

Comment: I want to store a style in my database. For example for user ranks they have a style you can change in the database (for example, Administrators have red text and is bold), so I want to place the administrators name with the style (for example, <b>) on the site and automatically close the tags that are in the style column. Sorry for my bad explaination, I'm Dutch..

Comment: what kind of output you expecting from above string

Comment: why don't you just create classes with the name of the role? and style these classes with the needed css?

Comment: Since you need to be able to add more ranks in the database and edit those styles without editing the .CSS files. So you can add a new rank and set the styles and the users with that rank will get that style for name

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
echo "<li id=''><a href='".$navigator['link']."'><span>".$navigator['style']. $navigator['title'].str_ireplace($navigator['style'], '<', '</') . "</span></a></li>";
```

Comment: It works but I was wondering if there's a better way or not, since it looks a bit messy to me. Or are there any other options I can do for styling except for HTML tags.